# Xcode entitlements "com.apple.security.inherit" seems like not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My MacOS application have a child process in its resources. I launch it up by NSTask.

In local debug, everything works well. But when I upload it to AppStore, Apple told me that my child process binary need a sandbox.

Ok, I set a sandbox to my binary, but new problem came up. The process can't run with NSTask, and the error code is 4, which means EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

All the thing I found is my binary need inherit its sandbox from the parent. I set these entitlements:

```
com.apple.security.inherit : true
com.apple.security.app-sandbox : true
```

Whatever, the problem still exist.

My app content is like this:

```
Contents
    - MacOS
        - mainExecutable
    - Frameworks
        - theFramework
    - Resources
        - theToolBinary
```

Their relationship is:

theToolBinary need theFramework to work. theToolBinary built on CommandLineTool and signed.

So, is the "com.apple.security.inherit" not working any more? Or what's wrong with my project?

Comment: Why I need a NSTask to launch is that the child process have its own User Interface.

Comment: Did you figure this out?